# How to automatically test if obfuscator was applied during build

Tags: java, testing, obfuscation

I am looking into creating an automated process that will check to see if the code was obfuscated during the release build or if for some reason the obfuscator didn't kick in.

Our codebase is in Java and although we might do some class name obfuscations we also do flow obfuscation with no name changes. Right now we're thinking of giving a manual process to the QA team to check for proper obfuscation before sending a release but I'd like to automate the task to avoid introducing possible human errors.

How would one go about this? Our java decompiler properly decompiles the code it's just not readable so I can't lean on a decompiler failure.

Comment: Heavily depends on your definition of proper obfuscation. No obfuscation is perfect. Obfuscation makes it more difficult to reverse engineer your code. While I personally think that's generally a bad thing to do, you can obviously do that. But how do you determine if an obfuscation is good? I think other than having someone try to reverse engineer your code there is not much you can do. A program will always be able to decompile your code, obfuscation is targetting other developers not software.

Comment: I have edited the question because it was misleading

Comment: If you simply want to check that an artifact has been obfuscated, why not just check that the jar contains a known obfuscated class name? This assumes the the obfuscator has no partial failure modes.